# Could not start the server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I had a problem like this when start server rails:
"Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, 2.1.5 specified but Gemfile guide"
how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

your version's arent on accord with each other.

run :

```
gem update --system
```

it will solve the issue